# Как распарсить XML в Yii2?

Tags: xml

xml в папке web :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<categories>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Nika</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Stepan</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Marusia</name>
    </item>
</categories>
```

Пытаюсь распарсить, не получается-ничего не выводит и ошибок тоже нет

```
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

//в цикле создаем объекты с параметрами, и пишем в базу
foreach($xmlData as $key => $item) {
    print_r($item->categories->item['name']);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь до файла, вероятнее всего скрипт ищет файл рядом с ним, а не в папке `web`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите полный путь до xml-файла. Сделать это можно примерно так:

```php
$xmlData = simplexml_load_file(\Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . '\\file.xml');

//в цикле создаем объекты с параметрами, и пишем в базу
foreach($xmlData as $key => $item) {
    print_r($item->categories->item['name']);
}
```